# Perl-script to read and print lines from multiple txt files?

Tags: perl, file

We have 300+ txt files, of which are basically replicates of an email, each txt file has the following format:

```
To: blabla@hotmail.com 
Subject: blabla 
From: bla1@hotmail.com 
Message: Hello World!
```

The platform I am to the script on is Windows, and everything is local (including the Perl instance). The aim is to write a script, which crawls through each file (all located within the same directory), and print out a list of each 'unique' email address in the from field. The concept is very easy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I know how to start off a Perl script, and I am able to read a single file and print all details:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/perl
 open (MYFILE, 'emails/email_id_1.txt');
 while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
 }
 close (MYFILE);
```

So now, I need to be able to read and print line 3 of this file, but perform this activity not just once, but for all of the files. I've looked into the File::Find module, could this be of any use?

Comment: I've discovered another command called 'readdir' to read form a single directory. I understand that File::Find is to read from multiple directories (within a tree structure), so 'readdir' may be more appropriate.

Comment: Why don't you use while (<>) to process all files given on the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

The `glob()` builtin can give you a list of files in a directory:

```
chdir $dir or die $!;
my @files = glob('*');
```

You can use `Tie::File` to access the 3rd line of a file:

```
use Tie::File;

for (@files) {
    tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $_ or die $!;
    print $lines[2], "\n";         
}
```

Comment: He will run into the rather vague error `Permission denied` when using that glob.

Answer (score 2):

What platform? If Linux then it's simple:

```
foreach $f (@ARGS) {    
    # Do stuff 
}
```

and then call with:

```
perl mything.pl *.txt
```

In Windows you'll need to expand the wildcard first as cmd.exe doesn't expand wildcards (unlike Linux shells):

```
@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV

foreach $f (@ARGS) {
    # Do stuff
}
```

then extracting the third line is just a simple case of reading each line in and counting when you've got to line 3 so you know to print the results.

Comment: It's as you had it -- just drop the code you've got inside where I've put `# Do stuff`, remembering to replace your hardcoded file with `$f`.

Comment: It's as simple in Windows. It's Perl. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl one-liner, windows-version:

```
perl -wE "@ARGV = glob '*.txt'; while (<>) { say $1 if /^From:\s*(.*)/ }"
```

It will check all the lines, but only print if it finds a valid From: tag.

Comment: +1: Nice to see that `glob` adds wildcard functionality to the DOS command-line. You might want to use `shift` instead of a hard-coded string for extra smilies :).

Comment: @zaid Don't you think it's overkill to have argument handling in a one-liner? :)

Comment: It's amusing to see Perl improving Windows ;)

Comment: DOS does have globs. Just not in perl args.

Comment: No I don't. DOS cmd shell is arcane and rudimentary. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Unix-style shell?  You can do this in the shell without even using Perl.

> grep "^From:" ./* | sort | uniq -c"

The breakdown is as follows:

1. grep will grab every line that starts with "From:", and send it to...
2. sort, which will alpha sort those lines, then...
3. uniq, which will filter out dupe lines.  The "-c" part will count the occurrences.

Your output would look like:

```
    3 From: dave@example.com
    5 From: foo@bar.example.com
    etc...
```

Possible issues:
I'm not sure how complex your "From" lines will be, e.g. multiple addresses, different formats, etc.

You could enhance that grep step in a few ways, or replace it with a Perl script that has less-broad functionality than your proposed all-in-one script.

Please comment if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Ah.  Well, you could install grep/sort/uniq unix tools on Windows and it would work, but I'm guessing that's not something you plan on doing.  Good luck!

Comment: `grep` with more than one file name argument prepends the file name to each line of output.  Use `grep -h` to avoid this.  The original problem doesn't require counting the occurrences, so `sort | uniq -c` could be replaced with `sort | uniq`, which in turn can be shortened to `sort -u`.  To get just the addresses, without the `From:` prefix: `sed -n '/^From: */s///p' * | sort -u`.

Comment: I guess I imagined the counting requirement, and yep, I forgot about the "grep -h" part.  Thanks for pointing out "sort -u"; sort is not something I use too often.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (I hope this isn't homework).

It checks all files in the current directory whose names end with ".txt", case-insensitive (e.g., it will find "foo.TXT", which is probably what you want under Windows).  It also allows for possible variations in line terminators (at least CR-LF and LF), and searches for the `From:` prefix case-insensitively, and allows arbitrary whitespace after the `:`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $DIR, '.' or die "opendir .: $!\n";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $DIR;
closedir $DIR;
# print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

my %seen = ();
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $FILE, '<', $file or die "$file: $!\n";
    while (<$FILE>) {
        if (/^From:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;
        }
    }
    close $FILE;
}

foreach my $addr (sort keys %seen) {
    print "$addr\n";
}
```